# How to check if a value is in a nested list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, search, nested

I want to check if a certain value is in a nested list. I've got a main list which contains more lists which can contain more lists and so on.. Just like this:

```
[['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 1]], 
['Hola',    1]], ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]
```

Now I want to check for example if there is 'Hiii' in one of the lists and if this is True, I want to change the second value of the list.

I tried it with recursion and a generator so far, but I acutally don't know how this is pretend to work.. And I don't know how I could change the second value of the lists...

```
def search(nested_list):
    for value in nested_list:
        for subvalue in search(value):
            yield subvalue
```

Thanks for your assistance in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
LoL=[['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 1]], 
['Hola',    1]], ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]
```

To *check* if a value is in a list of lists, first have a generator to flatten an arbitrary list of lists:

```
def flatten(it):
    for x in it:
        if (isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and
            not isinstance(x, str)):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

Then use `any`:

```
>>> any(x=="Hiii" for x in flatten(LoL))
True
>>> any(x=="BooHoo" for x in flatten(LoL))
False
```

---

To *change* a list of lists in place:

```
def LoLedit(li, tgt, nv):
    if isinstance(li, list):
        if li[0]==tgt: 
            li[1]=nv
        else:
            for next_item in li:
                LoLedit(next_item, tgt, nv)
    return li   

>>> LoLedit(LoL,"Hiii", "Changed")
[['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 'Changed']], ['Hola', 1]], ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]
```

Comment: Read the question carefully: how does this allow the user to change the second element of the list where the target was found?

Comment: not sure this answers how to update the second item in the list though

Answer (score 1):

You're on a right track, but you don't need a generator function here - simple recursion w/ find & change would suffice:

```
def search(source, find, new_value):
    if isinstance(source, list):  # no point searching in non-lists
        if find in source:
            source[1] = new_value
        else:
            for item in source:
                search(item, find, new_value)


data = [['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 1]], ['Hola', 1]],
        ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]

search(data, "Hiii", 5)

print(data)
# prints:
# [['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 5]], ['Hola', 1]],
# ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]
```

This is assuming that you don't want to do deeper search once you find your item.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic recursive function to find and update the value.

```
def search(n_list):
     for i in n_list:
         if isinstance(i, list):
             search(i)
         elif i == 'Hiii':
             try:
                 n_list[1] = # your value here
             except:
                 pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if a certain value is in a nested list (a list of lists) can be done using `recursion` :

```
# Flatten the list of lists into a simple list
def flatten_list(my_list, final=None):                                       
    if final is None:                                               
        final = []

    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            flatten_list(i, my_list)
        else:
            final.append(i)

    return final

a = [['Hey', 1], 0, 0, 0, ['Heyyy', 1], [[['Hi', 1], ['Hiii', 1]], 
['Hola',    1]], ['Hollaa', 2], ['Hallo', 1], 0, ['Hallooo', 1]]

check_element = lambda x, y: x in flatten_list(y)

# Some tests:
print(check_element('hey', a))
print(check_element('Hey', a))
print(check_element('Heyyy', a))
print(check_element('Hiii', a))
print(check_element(1, a))
print(check_element('foo', a))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
True
True
False
```